# React: How to navigate through list by arrow keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have build a simple component with a single text input and below of that a list (using semantic ui).

Now I would like to use the arrow keys to navigate through the list.

- First of all I have to select the first element. But how do I access a specific list element?
- Second I would get the information of the current selected element and select the next element. How do I get the info which element is selected?

Selection would mean to add the class `active` to the item or is there a better idea for that?

```
export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.state = { result: [] }
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Input onChange={ this.handleChange }/>
                <List>
                    {
                        result.map(i => {
                            return (
                                <List.Item key={ i._id } >
                                    <span>{ i.title }</span>
                                </List.Item>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </List>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask,  a component picture will be helpful to get awnser

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      cursor: 0,
      result: []
    }
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    const { cursor, result } = this.state
    // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
    if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      this.setState( prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor - 1
      }))
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < result.length - 1) {
      this.setState( prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor + 1
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { cursor } = this.state

    return (
      <Container>
        <Input onKeyDown={ this.handleKeyDown }/>
        <List>
          {
            result.map((item, i) => (
              <List.Item
                key={ item._id }
                className={cursor === i ? 'active' : null}
              >
                <span>{ item.title }</span>
              </List.Item>
            ))
          }
        </List>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

The cursor keeps track of your position in the list, so when the user presses the up or down arrow key you decrement/increment the cursor accordingly. The cursor should coincide with the array indices.

You probably want `onKeyDown` for watching the arrow keys instead of `onChange`, so you don't have a delay or mess with your standard input editing behavior.

In your render loop you just check the index against the cursor to see which one is active.

If you are filtering the result set based on the input from the field, you can just reset your cursor to zero anytime you filter the set so you can always keep the behavior consistent.

Comment: Edited to fix the down arrow condition. Accidentally typed > instead of <

Comment: it is recommended to use `e.key` since `e.keyCode` is deprecated

Comment: Good catch. Updated accordingly.

Comment: @shadymoses I think if you are using the `key` attribute you list the actual key value (e.g. `'ArrowDown'`) instead of the key code.  Also, I know there are some quirks re: browser support of `e.key` so worth checking before using.

Comment: You're right. `e.keyCode` gives the numeric key code and is better supported. Updated the answer again.

Comment: but if i hover on another list item both will have show highlighted how can i show at a time one as like in youtube search

Comment: Hover doesn't change the cursor you're tracking in this example. You can control this one of two ways: 1) just add a different style for hover vs focus so it's clearly different, 2) add a `mouseenter` event that will update the index.

Answer (score 87):

The accepted answer was very useful to me thanks! I adapted that solution and made a [react hooks flavoured version](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-navigate-list-with-keyboard-forked-7wjbh9), maybe it will be useful to someone:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const useKeyPress = function(targetKey) {
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const downHandler = ({ key }) => {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        setKeyPressed(true);
      }
    }
  
    const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        setKeyPressed(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    };
  }, [targetKey]);

  return keyPressed;
};

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "Josh Weir" },
  { id: 2, name: "Sarah Weir" },
  { id: 3, name: "Alicia Weir" },
  { id: 4, name: "Doo Weir" },
  { id: 5, name: "Grooft Weir" }
];

const ListItem = ({ item, active, setSelected, setHovered }) => (
  <div
    className={`item ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
    onClick={() => setSelected(item)}
    onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(item)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(undefined)}
  >
    {item.name}
  </div>
);

const ListExample = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);
  const downPress = useKeyPress("ArrowDown");
  const upPress = useKeyPress("ArrowUp");
  const enterPress = useKeyPress("Enter");
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length && downPress) {
      setCursor(prevState =>
        prevState < items.length - 1 ? prevState + 1 : prevState
      );
    }
  }, [downPress]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length && upPress) {
      setCursor(prevState => (prevState > 0 ? prevState - 1 : prevState));
    }
  }, [upPress]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length && enterPress) {
      setSelected(items[cursor]);
    }
  }, [cursor, enterPress]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length && hovered) {
      setCursor(items.indexOf(hovered));
    }
  }, [hovered]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <small>
          Use up down keys and hit enter to select, or use the mouse
        </small>
      </p>
      <span>Selected: {selected ? selected.name : "none"}</span>
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <ListItem
          key={item.id}
          active={i === cursor}
          item={item}
          setSelected={setSelected}
          setHovered={setHovered}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ListExample />, rootElement);
```

Attributing `useKeyPress` functionality to this [post](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/).

Comment: It is worth noting/attributing the `useKeyPress` functionality to this [post](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/).

Comment: This is working on the entire page and not within the specific component however. Is there a way to scope it to only when the dropdown is open?

Comment: You should probably add a dependency array to `useEffect`, and move `downHandler` and `upHandler` inside of the `useEffect` function. This way, it doesn't recreate the listener on each render.

Comment: This is dope! Can anyone explain the React.useEffect defined within useKeyPress? I'm don't understand why the event listeners are attached and detached in that particular way.

Comment: @FernandoRojo is right, otherwise the app is extremely slow

Comment: I have an issue with long list. It is acting weird when the list is scrollable. Not following active element, or first scrolls and then follows.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-navigate-list-with-keyboard-forked-t0hqum)

Comment: @corescan you should read about effects in React, which require useEffect. But the usage in this example is not proper, as I mentioned.

Comment: Updated the answer based on feedback thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Pretty much same solution as what @joshweir provided, but in Typescript. Also instead of 'window' object I used 'ref' and added the event listeners only to the input text box.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Dispatch, SetStateAction, createRef, RefObject } from "react";

const useKeyPress = function (targetKey: string, ref: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);


    const downHandler = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
        if (key === targetKey) {
            setKeyPressed(true);
        }
    }

    const upHandler = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
        if (key === targetKey) {
            setKeyPressed(false);
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        ref.current?.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
        ref.current?.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);

        return () => {
            ref.current?.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
            ref.current?.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
        };
    });

    return keyPressed;
};

const items = [
    { id: 1, name: "Josh Weir" },
    { id: 2, name: "Sarah Weir" },
    { id: 3, name: "Alicia Weir" },
    { id: 4, name: "Doo Weir" },
    { id: 5, name: "Grooft Weir" }
];

const i = items[0]
type itemType = { id: number, name: string }

type ListItemType = {
    item: itemType
    , active: boolean
    , setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SetStateAction<itemType | undefined>>>
    , setHovered: Dispatch<SetStateAction<itemType | undefined>>
}

const ListItem = ({ item, active, setSelected, setHovered }: ListItemType) => (
    <div
        className={`item ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => setSelected(item)}
        onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(item)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(undefined)}
    >
        {item.name}
    </div>
);

const ListExample = () => {
    const searchBox = createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<React.SetStateAction<itemType | undefined>>(undefined);
    const downPress = useKeyPress("ArrowDown", searchBox);
    const upPress = useKeyPress("ArrowUp", searchBox);
    const enterPress = useKeyPress("Enter", searchBox);
    const [cursor, setCursor] = useState<number>(0);
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState<itemType | undefined>(undefined);
    const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState<string>("")


    const handelChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSelected(undefined)
        setSearchItem(e.currentTarget.value)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (items.length && downPress) {
            setCursor(prevState =>
                prevState < items.length - 1 ? prevState + 1 : prevState
            );
        }
    }, [downPress]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (items.length && upPress) {
            setCursor(prevState => (prevState > 0 ? prevState - 1 : prevState));
        }
    }, [upPress]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (items.length && enterPress || items.length && hovered) {
            setSelected(items[cursor]);
        }
    }, [cursor, enterPress]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (items.length && hovered) {
            setCursor(items.indexOf(hovered));
        }
    }, [hovered]);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <small>
                    Use up down keys and hit enter to select, or use the mouse
        </small>
            </p>
            <div>
                <input ref={searchBox} type="text" onChange={handelChange} value={selected ? selected.name : searchItem} />
                {items.map((item, i) => (
                    <ListItem

                        key={item.id}
                        active={i === cursor}
                        item={item}
                        setSelected={setSelected}
                        setHovered={setHovered}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ListExample />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Why do you need hovered state?

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt, with the downside that it requires the rendered children to pass `ref` correctly:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, cloneElement, Children, isValidElement } from "react";

export const ArrowKeyListManager: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0)
  const items = useRef<HTMLElement[]>([])

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    let newCursor = 0
    if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      newCursor = Math.min(cursor + 1, items.current.length - 1)
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      newCursor = Math.max(0, cursor - 1)
    }
    setCursor(newCursor)
    const node = items.current[newCursor]
    node?.focus()
  }

  return (
    <div onKeyDown={onKeyDown} {...props}>
      {Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        if (isValidElement(child)) {
          return cloneElement(child, {
            ref: (n: HTMLElement) => {
              items.current[index] = n
            },
          })
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ArrowKeyListManager>
        <button onClick={() => alert('first')}>First</button>
        <button onClick={() => alert('second')}>Second</button>
        <button onClick={() => alert('third')}>third</button>
     </ArrowKeyListManager>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a list with children that can be navigated by pressing the left-right & up-down key bindings.

Recipe.

1. Create an Array of Objects that will be used as a list using a map function on the data.
2. Create a useEffect and add an Eventlistener to listen for keydown actions in the window.
3. Create handleKeyDown function in order to configure the navigation behaviour by tracking the key that was pressed, use their keycodes fo that.

   keyup: e.keyCode === 38

   keydown: e.keyCode === 40

   keyright: e.keyCode === 39

   keyleft: e.keyCode === 37
4. Add State

let [activeMainMenu, setActiveMainMenu] = useState(-1);

let [activeSubMenu, setActiveSubMenu] = useState(-1);

5. Render by Mapping through the Array of objects

   ```
        <ul ref={WrapperRef}>
          {navigationItems.map((navigationItem, Mainindex) => {
            return (
              <li key={Mainindex}>
                {activeMainMenu === Mainindex
                  ? "active"
                  : navigationItem.navigationCategory}
                <ul>
                  {navigationItem.navigationSubCategories &&
                    navigationItem.navigationSubCategories.map(
                      (navigationSubcategory, index) => {
                        return (
                          <li key={index}>
                            {activeSubMenu === index
                              ? "active"
                              : navigationSubcategory.subCategory}
                          </li>
                        );
                      }
                    )}
                </ul>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
   ```

Find the above solution in the following link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-list-accessible-with-keys-9pm3i1?file=/src/App.js:2811-3796

Answer (score -1):

## 2 search bars with dropdown suggestions, selectable by both mouse and arrow keys (TypeScript)

```css
li.cursor {
    background: yellow;
}
#Item\ 1, #Item\ 2  {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```
import { StateUpdater, useState } from "preact/hooks";

const list1 = ['rabbits', 'raccoons', 'reindeer', 'red pandas', 'rhinoceroses', 'river otters', 'rattlesnakes', 'roosters'] 
const list2 = ['jacaranda', 'jacarta', 'jack-o-lantern orange', 'jackpot', 'jade', 'jade green', 'jade rosin', 'jaffa'];

type List = string[]
type SearchList = List | null
type SelectedItem = string | null
/** Cursor is the current highlighted item in the search list. It's null when the mouse leaves */
type Cursor = number | null ; 

/** Active list is used to determine whether the search list should be popup or not */
type ListName = '1' | '2' | null
type ActiveList = ListName

function SearchList({listName, searchList, cursor, setCursor, setSelectedItem}: {listName: ListName, searchList: SearchList, cursor: Cursor, setCursor: StateUpdater<Cursor>, setSelectedItem: StateUpdater<SelectedItem>} ) {
  if (!searchList) return
  const id = `Search list ${listName}`
  return (
    <ul id={id} className='active'>
      {searchList.map((item, index) => (
        <li 
          key={index}
          className={cursor === index ? 'cursor' : ''}
          onClick={() => setSelectedItem(item)}
          onMouseEnter={() => setCursor(index)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setCursor(null)}
        >{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )      
}

function SearchDiv({listName, list, activeList, setActiveList}: {listName: '1' | '2', list: List, activeList: ActiveList, setActiveList: StateUpdater<ActiveList>}){
  const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState<null | SearchList>(null);
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState<Cursor>(0); 
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<null | SelectedItem>(null); 

  function handleKeyDown (e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (!list) return
    if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      const newCursor = Math.min(cursor! + 1, list.length - 1);
      setCursor(newCursor);
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      const newCursor = Math.max(0, cursor! - 1);
      setCursor(newCursor);
    } else if (e.key === "Enter" && cursor) {
      setSelectedItem(list[cursor]) 
    } 
  };

  const searchListNode = <SearchList listName={listName} searchList={searchList} cursor={cursor} setCursor={setCursor} setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} />
  return (
    <div 
      id={`search-div-${listName}`}
      className="search-bar-container"
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder={`Search list ${listName}`}
        onInput={(e) => {
          setSearchList(list.filter(item => item.includes((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)));
        }}
        onFocus={() => setActiveList(listName)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
      /><br />
      {activeList === listName ? searchListNode : null}
      Cursor: {cursor}<br />
      Selected item of list {listName}: <span id={`Item ${listName}`}>{selectedItem}</span><br />
    </div>
  ) 
} 

export default function SearchBarSplit() {
  /** Active list is used to determine whether the search list should be popup or not */
  const [activeList, setActiveList] = useState<ActiveList>(null); 
  return (
    <>
      <SearchDiv listName="1" list={list1} activeList={activeList} setActiveList={setActiveList} />
      <SearchDiv listName="2" list={list2} activeList={activeList} setActiveList={setActiveList} />
      Active list: <strong>{activeList}</strong>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]