# How can I navigate through a list using arrow keys in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, tsx

I am modifying an existing react application where I display a list, and would like to navigate through the list using the up/down arrow keys. Right now, I can't seem to get the onKeyDown event to fire when I place it in the div.

Before anybody tags as duplicate, I have looked through related questions and can't seem to work the solutions into my own code - they don't work for me. I was most recently trying to follow the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036865/react-how-to-navigate-through-list-by-arrow-keys) and was able to get event to register when I add to an input div tag, but not on its own.
I've placed it in a few different div tags to try to get it in the right spot, but nothing seems to work for me.

I tried adding the following to the div tags below: 
`onKeyDown={() => console.log("keyPressed"}` I've also tried adding tabIndex="0" but I get an error about assigning a string to a number.

```
return(
     <BaseLayout>
         <div className="top-container">
         <div id="primary-view">
         <myList className="custom-list-a" items={allListItems} />
)
```

There are other elements on the page, I'd like to just be iterating through my list with the up and down arrow keys. (I have a separate irrelevant function called onKeyPressed that will increment the index etc, I'm just needing the event to be responded to.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you throw this on a codesandbox?

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [arrow, updateState] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if(e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        updateState(String.fromCharCode(8595));
      } else if(e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        updateState(String.fromCharCode(8593))
      }
    })
  }), [];
  return <p>{arrow}</p>
}
```

[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-afw18w)

Comment: Without a little more to go on, there's no way to know what that even means