# How to make notification list elements traversable through key up and down button in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility

I have written this react component where I want the list element to be traversable thorough the key up and down buttons. I am able to do using tab-index with tab and shift tab, but instead I want to use key up and down.

````
export const NotificationListComponent: React.FunctionComponent<INotifications> = (
  props
) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.notifications &&
        props.notifications.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.notificationId}
              style={NotificationListStyle}
              role="listitem"
              tabIndex={0}
            >
              <NotificationItemComponent {...item} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};```
````

Comment: May be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036865/react-how-to-navigate-through-list-by-arrow-keys

Comment: I have seen this link but i dont want all those think i just want to navigate the list item.I dont want mouse event and all i just want key up and down traversal of list element

Comment: What do you mean by key up and key down?  What keys on the keyboard will the user be using?  Not the arrow keys?  OK, then what keys?

Comment: There are not mouse events there, only key events - `handle**Key**Down`

Comment: https://dev.to/rafi993/roving-focus-in-react-with-custom-hooks-1ln
This might help.