# Allow to select a tag not only with the mouse cursor but also with the up and down keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags

On the site in the search box, it is possible to enter one or more letters and get options that satisfy the search. Further, the selected option will be displayed as a tag and the database will be searched in accordance with the user's request.

Everything works correctly, but I would like to improve the functionality a little. As you can see, in the example above, only the mouse cursor is allowed to add a tag (the up-down keys and the enter key do not work). Please tell me how to make it so that the user can also select tags using the up-down keys and the enter key.

```
export default function TagsInput(props) {
    const {tags, setTags, tagSuggestions} = props;
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [suggestedTags, setSuggestedTags] = useState([]);
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
  
    const onChange = (e) => {
      const { value } = e.target;
      setInput(value)
  
      if(value.length < 1) { setSuggestedTags([]); setIsValid([]);return; }
      
      const matchedSuggestions = tagSuggestions.filter(s =>
        s.startsWith(value) && 
        !tags.includes(s)                  
    );
      setSuggestedTags(matchedSuggestions); 

      


    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
      const { key } = e;
      const trimmedInput = input.trim();
      if ((key === "") &&
        trimmedInput.length &&
        !tags.includes(trimmedInput)
      ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTags((prevState) => [...prevState, trimmedInput]);
        setInput("");
      }
    };
  
    const deleteTag = (index) => {
      setTags((prevState) => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index));
    };
  
    const selectTag = (tag) => {
      setTags((prevState) => [...prevState, tag]);
      setSuggestedTags([]);
      setInput("");
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => <div className={classes.tag} key={tag}>
            <ClearIcon
              className={classes.del}
              fontSize="big"
              onClick={() => deleteTag(index)}
            />
            {tag}
          </div>
        )}

        <input
          className={classes.input}
          value={input}
          placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          onChange={onChange}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        />

     
        {suggestedTags.length ? (
              <div className={classes.tagSuggestionWrapper}>
                {suggestedTags.map((tag) => {
                  return (<div key={tag} 
                              className={classes.tagSuggestion} 
                              onClick={() => { selectTag(tag) }}>{tag}</div>
                              );            
                })}
              </div>
            ) : null }

        
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to navigate through list by arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036865/react-how-to-navigate-through-list-by-arrow-keys)

Comment: @atadurdyyewserdar Perhaps there is something in common, but the approach is different. I will now try to adapt that answer to fit my code. Thanks for the advice. However, if you can help me with the code and I will gladly accept your help.

Comment: Please include all relevant code (a [mre]) in the question itself, not only on an external site like Code Sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution.

When you press arrow button:

1. If it is ArrowDown:
   set currentIndex to prev + 1
2. Else if it is ArrowUp
   set currentIndex to prev - 1
3. Else if it is Enter
   add item with currentIndex to selected items

Then you just check if currentIndex matches with index in map and change bg color.

Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-herschel-5wgovi?file=/src/TagsInput.js:0-2456).

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. But I use the link provided by you, I still can’t use arrows. They don't work anyway

Comment: I forgot to add style selected. Check now.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you! I will analyze your code to understand your approach

Comment: I am trying to understand your code and adapt it to my own. I begin to understand your logic, but I still do not go out to adapt your code to my working code. I slightly changed the codesandbox specified in the task (now there is the current code that I use at the moment). Could you help me with the current code.

Comment: Check the same link.

Comment: Make sure that you also added styles as well as to styles file and in your div component. Check style.css file and div component in given example.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across such situation and i have implemented somewhat similar to this.
You need to bind the keydown event and based on entered key you can take necessary action.

Here i have created one state to keep track of which tag is currently highlighted and we can manipulate that counter on key events.

```
import React from "react";
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";
import classes from "./TagsInput.module.css";

export default function TagsInput(props) {
  const tags = props.tags;
  const setTags = props.setTags;
  const tagSuggestions = props.tagSuggestions;
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
  const [suggestedTags, setSuggestedTags] = React.useState([]);
  const [hoveredItem, setHoveredItem] = React.useState(-1);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setInput(value);

    if (value.trim() === "") {
      setSuggestedTags([]);
      setHoveredItem(-1);
      return;
    }

    populateSuggestedTags(value);
  };

  const populateSuggestedTags = (value) => {
    const keyword = value || input;
    setSuggestedTags(
      tagSuggestions.filter(
        (s) =>
          s.toLowerCase().search(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1 &&
          !tags.includes(s)
      )
    );
  };

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const { key } = e;
    const trimmedInput = input.trim();
    if (key === " " && trimmedInput === "") {
      // When spacebar is entered display list
      e.preventDefault();
      populateSuggestedTags();
      setInput("");
    } else if (
      key === "Escape" ||
      (key === "Backspace" && trimmedInput === "")
    ) {
      // Escape or backspace will close the list
      e.preventDefault();
      clearFields();
    } else if (key === "ArrowDown") {
      // tags will highlight when arrow down
      e.preventDefault();
      if (suggestedTags.length && hoveredItem < suggestedTags.length - 1) {
        setHoveredItem((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      } else {
        populateSuggestedTags();
      }
    } else if (key === "ArrowUp") {
      // tags will highlight when arrow up
      e.preventDefault();
      if (suggestedTags.length && hoveredItem > 0) {
        setHoveredItem((prevState) => prevState - 1);
      }
    } else if (key === "Enter") {
      // tags will gets selected
      e.preventDefault();
      if (hoveredItem > -1) {
        selectTag(suggestedTags[hoveredItem]);
      }
    }
  };

  const deleteTag = (index) => {
    setTags((prevState) => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const selectTag = (tag) => {
    setTags((prevState) => [...prevState, tag]);
    clearFields();
  };

  const clearFields = () => {
    setSuggestedTags([]);
    setInput("");
    setHoveredItem(-1);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      {tags.map((tag, index) => (
        <div className={classes.tag} key={tag}>
          <ClearIcon
            className={classes.del}
            fontSize="big"
            onClick={() => deleteTag(index)}
          />
          {tag}
        </div>
      ))}
      <input
        className={classes.input}
        value={input}
        placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      {suggestedTags.length > 0 && (
        <div className={classes.tagSuggestionWrapper}>
          {suggestedTags.map((t, i) => {
            const cls = i === hoveredItem ? classes.hoveredSuggestion : "";
            return (
              <div
                key={t}
                className={`${cls}`}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredItem(i)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredItem(-1)}
                onClick={() => {
                  selectTag(t);
                }}
              >
                {t}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-diffie-33wufd?file=/src/TagsInput.js

You need to test this and alter if required according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Your solution is great. I will analyze every line in order to understand what magic you used. Thank you!